# Testing Hard Drive Performance

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, performance

I am trying to compare performance of several hard drives in my current system, and downloaded performance test 9.0 to try to run some comparisons.  Things were going well until I ran the test on a 1TB western digital drive, and I am having a hard time believing the results, and now they are all suspect in my mind.  This is the specs for the drive
http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4853015

I have run multiple tests, with different file sizes and I am consistently get over 700MB/Sec for the read tests.  I can't believe that is true, so im assuming something is off with the tests, but the results for my other drives look correct/reasonable.

PerformanceTest Results can be seen [image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bjs4ZONYePHO9uJK4HvmejVOCV2ObLZE/view]

So, one just to make sure im not loosing my mind, there isn't a cache system, of anything that could make these results legit right?  Assuming thats the case, can anyone recommend a good performance test tool for testing hard drives?

Since the question was unclear I was looking for two things. 
1. A sanity check that I wasn't over looking something stupid that could be cause the test to be skewed. 
2. A good way to preform a general performance test against multiple drives to compare the drives against each other.

Comment: Here is some user brenchmarks for Seagate Barracuda 1TB drive to compare: http://hdd.userbenchmark.com/Seagate-Barracuda-1TB-2016/Rating/3896 . Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it is something wrong with the testing software. You can change a hard drive software and have a try. Try the software HDD scan.

Comment: Can you tell us the model of the drive? Your question is attracting close votes due to the lack of data, could you possibly include the output?

Comment: I updated the question.  I included the drive specs, and a screenshot of the test results.

Comment: Maybe caching is the cause of the problems. Just make the test file 2x your ram, and test again.

Comment: It's word, I ran the same test on 4 other drives in the pc, they all came back with around where I expected, this is the only anomoly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking at a drive whose firmware has been written to detect benchmark tests and cheat in various ways. (Yes, drive manufacturers have done that.) Try an ordinary real-world test, like copy a large file to the drive, then shut down and power down (to clear OS and drive caches), then copy it back to another place on the origin drive.

Certainly something is off. the specs for that drive have it at only SATA 3 Gb/s, which is 300 MB/s (that's at the SATA connector and is the maximum burst speed possible between drive cache and the motherboard interface - never mind actually reading and writing the media). 700 MB/s would be over twice that fast!  And the "internal data rate" (that's between the media and the drive internal cache) is only 111 MB/s! So clearly a measurement of 700 MB/s cannot be correct. There is a mistake somewhere. Maybe several somewheres.

Comment: That seems to make as much sense as anything else I can think of.  I was hoping to be able to use a bench mark tool so I would have a consistent set of results to compare across multiple drives, but that may just not be an option.  thanks